# Neo4J Query to Retrieve data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a query in Neo4J (which is something I'm literally learning as I go) but I am struggling. So I am using the Neo4J sandbox and movie data set provided (:play movie-graph). This is what I am looking for...

1. Create a query to retrieve all the movie directors that worked with actors 55 years or older at the time the movie was released
2. Display the networks of actors, writers, and movies for these actors

This is what I have but I'm sure it is completely wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
MATCH (directors)<-[:DIRECTED]-(directors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(actors)-(actors: Age) WHERE actors.age >= 55 RETURN directors.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query which will return all directors who directed movies wit actors born before 1970. Change the year to any year you need it to be to satisfy your criteria.

```
MATCH (q)-[r:DIRECTED]->(k)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(s) where s.born<1970  RETURN DISTINCT q;
```

Few suggestions for you,

. Understand neo4j nodes and relationships. In your query, you have written (directors), (actors) etc.

I dont find these entities in the movie dataset. It shows that you need to understand these concepts and how these are represented in the queries. The browser console shows these entities clearly.

. Understand relationship directions and how they are represented in the queries.

. Modify the above query in small ways and see how the results changes. For ex,  instead of q, return s. Remove DISTINCT clause etc.

. Finally create your own custom data set and try out queries.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To find the names of directors who directed movies that had an actor aged 55+ at the time the movie was released, you can take advantage of the new [existential subquery in neo4j 4.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/where/#existential-subquery-with-where):

```
MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:WROTE]->(w)
WHERE m.released-actor.born >= 55
RETURN actor, COLLECT(DISTINCT m) AS movies, COLLECT(DISTINCT w) AS writers
```

To get the actors who were 55+ at the time a movie they were in was released, along with a list of those movies and a list of their writers:

```
MATCH (w)-[:WROTE]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person)
WHERE m.released-actor.born >= 55
RETURN actor, COLLECT(DISTINCT m) AS movies, COLLECT(DISTINCT w) AS writers
```